# Difference between std::string and vector<char> in C++

Tags: c++, string, std, stdvector, stdstring

An academic C++ programming course [http://www.dcs.bbk.ac.uk/~roger/cpp/week6.htm](http://www.dcs.bbk.ac.uk/%7Eroger/cpp/week6.htm) says that

> In C++ a string behaves in many ways like a vector of char elements; in particular, you can use the square-bracket operator to access a single character.

Therefore, after reading *in many ways similar*, I understand there are some differences.

1. What are the diffrences between an std::string and std::vector?
2. What is exactly an std::string *internally*, if it is not a 100% std::vector?